# How to change cursor color in jupyterlab

Tags: css, user-interface, jupyter-lab

when using the dark mode of Chrome, the jupyterlab cursor is invisible, since it's black by default.

Any workaround?

Comment: Please open an issue on https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab as this sounds like a bug

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.
Find all index.css files in the following paths:

```
~\anaconda3\pkgs\jupyterlab-3.4.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0\share\jupyter\lab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-dark-extension\index.css
```

Search for `--jp-ui-font-color0`, and change the color index following it to anything you want.

There're many `index.css` on my PC. Since you may use different theme from I did, you can modify all `index.css` files in `~\anaconda3\pkgs\jupyterlab-3.4.2-pyhd8ed1ab_0\`. And I tested it, it worked.